# Installing WordPress cherry template

Tags: wordpress

I tried to install a cherry template. The first  I imported the sample_data files, it works but the site it doesn't look like the demo live site. So I decided to re-import the sample_data files and every time I try to re-import them I got the following error :

Importing XMLInstalling content error.

I appreciate every help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your upload_maxfilesize in your php.ini. The xml file you're trying to upload is probably bigger than what you can upload. Here's a tutorial on how to change your upload_maxfilesize. http://wptheming.com/2009/07/upload_max_filesize/

Comment: I have already changed the upload_maxfilesize via the WordPress Dashbaord. This is not enough ??

Comment: What is the upload size now and how big is the xml file?

Comment: the upload size is 10MB

Comment: what about the file?

Comment: The size of the files  is 8,6MB.

Comment: I have no idea how you changed the upload size through the WP dashboard. Could you please check your php.ini file anyways? or place it here somewhere.

Comment: I checked the WordPress directory and I didn't find the php.ini

Comment: php.ini is not a part of Wordpress. Its a file that you can find in your php installation folder.

Comment: where can I find it exactly ???

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I changed the upload_maxfilesize But I still have the same problem. 
??

Comment: I use AWS, Amazon Linux (Linux webserver).